# Matlab: Efficiently do SVD many times? (to triangulate a 3D point cloud)

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, svd, point-clouds

**The context:** Performing triangulation on many point pairs, 2d to 3d. The equation I have is:

```
Mv = 0    with    M = [P1 -x1 0]  (6x6 matrix)      v = [X, lambda1, lambda2]^T (6x1)
                      [P2 0 -x2]
```

where P1, P2 are 3x4 projection matrices, x1 and x2 are 2D projections of the 3D point X, and the lambdas are just parameters for representing the line-plane intersection (not important). All of this is done in homogeneous coordinates, so M is 6x6.

**The problem:** By doing a SVD on M, I can get a least squares triangulation of the two 2D points x1 and x2 to get a 3D point. If I repeat this on all point pairs I can obtain a point cloud. However, it is extremely inefficient to repeatedly compute SVD that many times in a for loop; mainly, I would have to construct each matrix by inserting the points first, then doing SVD. Is there a way I can vectorize the SVD computation on a list of point pairs?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Today I've thought about how to solve it. And due to how SVD for triangulation works, I worry that for triangulating 1000 points you would have to solve svd for a matrix 1000x1000 (though it would be pretty sparse - just 4x4 blocks on the diagonal). That way, I think you would get no more efficient than using a for loop. But I'm not giving any proofs...

Comment: Just a performance improvement - if you triangulate euclidean points (not homogeneous), you save one coordinate per point, which means `M` becomes 4x4 and thus much easier to SVD. The change in the algorithm is then that you no longer solve a homogeneous set of equations, but a non-homogeneous (instead of Ax=0 you solve Ax=b).

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [triangulate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/triangulate.html) function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.